# How to differentiate Windows Hello vs WH for Business?

Tags: windows-hello

My company is studying whether to deploy WH or WH for Business (WH4B). We're a few people working on that, with a lot of shadow governance. That's an issue, but off-topic here.

WH or WH4B has been installed on my computer running W10 Enterprise. It works. I can connect using face, fingerprint, or 6-digit PIN.

- **How do I know whether it's WH or WH4B that's running?**

I've been told it's WH not WH4B. However, it unlocks my regular AD account (already set up and used before). I'm a bit suspicious.

- **Where can I find technical information about WH or WH4B?**

I can only find marketing/layman's presentation on microsoft.com. I can't find how WH/WH4B is working, the data exchanged with the TPM, the AD, key derivation, etc.

My objective is to understand the underlying risks of a larger deployment.

Comment: [Microsoft docs: Windows Hello for Business Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-overview)

Comment: [More specifically, this "Deep Dive" section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-how-it-works-technology)